# Define Numpy array and assign values in single line

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a way of doing the following

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)
x[2:7] = 1
```

In a single line? Something like

```
x = np.arange(10)[2:7] = 1
```

Comment: @Minato No, this is just an example, I'm looking for a general solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One-liner using `masking` with [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for assigning values -

```
np.where(np.in1d(range(10),range(2,7)), 1, range(10))
```

Sample run -

```
In [28]: np.where(np.in1d(range(10),range(2,7)), 1, range(10))
Out[28]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9])
```

Step-by-step run -

Get mask where new values are to be assigned :

```
In [44]: np.in1d(range(10),range(2,7))
Out[44]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  \
                True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Use the mask alongwith `np.where` to choose between new value `(=1)` and the originally defined values - `range(10)` :

```
In [45]: np.where(np.in1d(range(10),range(2,7)), 1, range(10))
Out[45]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9])
```

Thus, to summarize, the syntax is basically -

```
np.where(np.in1d(range(10),range(2,7)), 1, range(10))
                        ^         ^     ^       ^
                       (1)       (2)   (3)  <--(4)-->
```

(1) Length of array to be defined.

(2) Slicing limits.

(3) New value(s) to be assigned as the second step.

(4) Values that were initialized to array at the time of defining it.

Here's another sample usage -

```
In [41]: np.where(np.in1d(range(9),range(2,7)), 99, range(10,19))
Out[41]: array([10, 11, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 17, 18])
```

The original styled code to reproduce it would be -

```
x = np.arange(10,19)
x[2:7] = 99
```

Comment: While this is functionally an excellent answer, I think this one liner is a lot less readable than the original two line version. So unless doing it this way improves performace (memory or speed) I think the two line approach is preferred. Or at least make sure to comment the one liner sufficiently.

Comment: @HannesOvrén Agreed on the readability issue. Even with performance/memory, the original two-liner would be better. Added few comments /explanation.

Answer (score 1):

While Divakar's answer does the job, it is not good for readability. There's a more numpy-esque way of doing this, using [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), which is essentially performing concatenation, but you can specify arrays using slices.

From the examples in the documentation (slightly modified by me):

```
>>> np.r_[1:4, 0, 0, 4:7]
array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6])
>>> np.r_[-1:1:6j, [0]*3, 5, 6]
array([-1. , -0.6, -0.2,  0.2,  0.6,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  5. ,  6. ])
```

For your specific example,

```
>>> np.r_[0:2, [1,]*5, 7:10]
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack):

```
np.hstack((np.arange(2), np.ones(7-2), np.arange(7,10)))
```

and multiply `np.ones` with whichever number you need. Should be straightforward to extend it to arbitrary input numbers.

[image]